# Custom Options not showing when creating order in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.9

I assume this is a magento bug. When I try to place an order via Magento Admin Order Create, the custom options for the product do not show up. However, the custom options works well from the frontend. See image.

How can I resolve this? Thanks for helping out.

[image: Missing Custom Options]

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you use customer module
 What is the name of the module?